# g3d and visual studio 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl

I just freshly installed visual studio 2010 on my laptop and set up g3d aswell.  I then opened a sample project that came with the g3d download to test if I had it set up right.  The build was successful but when it came to executing the project i got this error [image: g3d error]

My laptop is new and g3d ran fine on my old laptop so i dont understand this.  The new laptop however has switchable graphics.  The chips that are in it are :
Radeon (TM) HD 7470M and Intel(R) HD Graphics Family

Answer (score 0):

Well just in case anyone else was wondering what the answer was to this is it was a hp problem, the dual graphics card in my computer wasnt being picked up.  I had to download the CCC Catalyst Control Centre and allow the programs access the radeon graphics chip in my laptop.